Find coefficients of the inverse of a matrix holding sum of binomial coefficients
For a given $n$, we define the coefficient $\beta_{i}(k)$ with the following (some context here):
\begin{align*}
\beta_{i}(k) = \sum_{u=0}^{k} (-1)^u \cdot {n \choose u} \cdot {n-i \choose k-u} 
\end{align*}
and define the $n+1$ square matrix $M_n$:
\begin{equation*}
M_n = \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
\beta_{0}(0) & \beta_{1}(0) & ... & \beta_{n}(0) \\
\beta_{0}(2) & \beta_{1}(2) & ... & \beta_{n}(2) \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
\beta_{0}(2n) & \beta_{1}(2n) & ... & \beta_{n}(2n) 
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation*}
Question: is it possible to find an explicit formula for the coefficients of the inverse of $M_n$ ?
So far, I just managed to have some numerical experiments that seem to show some pattern. For instance, we can use gp/pari with:
beta(n,i,k) =  (1+(-1)^k) * sum(u=0,k, (-1)^u*binomial(n,u)*binomial(n-i,k-u));
M(n) = matrix (n+1,n+1,x,y, beta(n,y-1,2*(x-1)));

and get for instance
? 1/M(5)*2^5
%3 = 
[   0    0    0    0     0    -16]

[35/8 -5/8  3/8 -5/8  35/8  315/8]

[35/8 -5/8  3/8 -5/8 -93/8 -325/8]

[15/4 -1/4 -1/4 15/4  47/4   95/4]

[ 5/2  1/2 -3/2 -7/2 -11/2  -15/2]

[   1    1    1    1     1      1]

and
? 1/M(6)*2^6
%4 = 
[   0    0    0    0    0     0     32]

[63/8 -7/8  3/8 -3/8  7/8 -63/8 -693/8]

[63/8 -7/8  3/8 -3/8  7/8 193/8  843/8]

[   7 -1/2    0  1/2   -7 -61/2    -78]

[21/4  1/4 -3/4  9/4 37/4  81/4  141/4]

[   3    1   -1   -3   -5    -7     -9]

[   1    1    1    1    1     1      1]

Moreover, WolframAlpha tells that $\beta_{i}(k)$ is related to the following hypergeometric function:
\begin{align*}
\beta_{i}(k) = {n-i \choose k} \,\, _2F_1\left(-k,-n; -k-i+n+1; -1 \right)
\end{align*}
which may be useful (but not found how to use it).
I also considered using the Caley-Hamilton theorem in order to compute the inverse matrix but computing the powers of $M_n$ and the characteristic polynomial doesn't seem to be an easy task.
Maybe there is a clever way to get an explicit formula for the inverse of $M_n$ but I have not found it so far (keep trying).
Update 1
Some numerical experiments seem to show that the coefficients of row $r$ of the $2^n/M_n$ matrix are the values of a polynomial of degree $(n+1-r)$ for $t=0,1,...n$.
For instance for the $2^5/M_5$ matrix, these "generating" polynomials are:
\begin{align*}
(-32\,t^5 + 320\,t^4 - 1120\,t^3 + 1600\,t^2 - 768\,t)  \,/\, (2\cdot 5!) \\
(32\,t^4 - 256\,t^3 + 688\,t^2 - 704\,t + 210) \,/\, (2\cdot 4!)\\
(-16\,t^3 + 84\,t^2 - 128\,t + 105/2) \,/\, (2\cdot 3!) \\
(8\,t^2 - 24\,t + 15) \,/\, (2\cdot 2!)\\
(-4\,t + 5) \,/\, (2\cdot 1!) \\
(2) \,/\, (2\cdot 0!)
\end{align*}
and for the $2^6/M_6$ matrix:
\begin{align*}
(64\,t^6 - 960\,t^5 + 5440\,t^4 - 14400\,t^3 + 17536\,t^2 - 7680\,t)  \,/\, (2\cdot 6!) \\
(-64\,t^5 + 800\,t^4 - 3680\,t^3 + 7600\,t^2 - 6756\,t + 1890)   \,/\, (2\cdot 5!)\\
(32\,t^4 - 288\,t^3 + 880\,t^2 - 1044\,t + 378)   \,/\, (2\cdot 4!)\\
(-16\,t^3 + 96\,t^2 - 170\,t + 84)   \,/\, (2\cdot 3!)\\
(8\,t^2 - 28\,t + 21)   \,/\, (2\cdot 2!)\\
(-4\,t + 6)   \,/\, (2\cdot 1!)\\
(2)   \,/\, (2\cdot 0!)
\end{align*}
Other polynomials can be found for other tested $n$ values. So, finding for each $n$ an explicit formula for these polynomials would answer the question.
Update 2
Here is some gp/pari code that looks for the "generating" polynomials:
Factorial(n) = round(factorial(n));

fit(X,Y) =  matsolve (matrix (length(X),length(X),r,c, X[r]^(c-1)) ,Y~); 

beta(n,i,k) =  (1+(-1)^k) * sum(u=0,k, (-1)^u*binomial(n,u)*binomial(n-i,k-u));

M(n) = matrix (n+1,n+1,x,y, beta(n,y-1,2*(x-1)));

Mfit(n) = 
{
  res = matrix(n+1,n+1,x,y,0);
  mm  = 1/M(n)*2^n; 
  nm = length(mm);
  forstep (r=1, nm, 1,
    rf = fit (vector(nm,x,x-1), vector(nm,x,mm[r,x])); 
    for (p=1,nm, res[r,p] = 2*Factorial(nm-r)* rf[p] );
  );
  return (res);
}

We can test for $n=5$ with:
r = Mfit (5);  vp = vector(length(r), n, sum(i=0,length(r)-1, t^i*r[n,i+1]));  
for (n=1,length(vp), print("\n[",n,"] ----------------------------------------\n","    ", vp[n],"\n", "    ", factor(vp[n])))

which gives the polynomials (and their factorization):
[1] ----------------------------------------
    -32*t^5 + 320*t^4 - 1120*t^3 + 1600*t^2 - 768*t
    [t - 4, 1; t - 3, 1; t - 2, 1; t - 1, 1; t, 1]

[2] ----------------------------------------
    32*t^4 - 256*t^3 + 688*t^2 - 704*t + 210
    [2*t - 7, 1; 2*t - 5, 1; 2*t - 3, 1; 2*t - 1, 1]

[3] ----------------------------------------
    -16*t^3 + 84*t^2 - 128*t + 105/2
    [4*t - 7, 1; 8*t^2 - 28*t + 15, 1]

[4] ----------------------------------------
    8*t^2 - 24*t + 15
    Mat([8*t^2 - 24*t + 15, 1])

[5] ----------------------------------------
    -4*t + 5
    Mat([4*t - 5, 1])

[6] ----------------------------------------
    2
    matrix(0,2)

For many tested $n$, the first two polynomials seem to be:
\begin{align*}
(-1)^n \cdot 2^n \cdot \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (t-k)  \\
(-1)^{n+1} \cdot 2 \cdot \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \Big(2\,t-(2\,k-1) \Big)  \\
\end{align*}
It doesn't look too difficult to find formulas for the last two polynomials for any $n$, but intermediate ones are less obvious to infer.
Another observation: the roots of these polynomials seem to be all real and positive and each root of the polynomial for row $r+1$ is bracketed between two roots of the polynomial of row $r$, e.g. for $n=5$
? for (n=1, length(vp)-1,  print ("\n------------------------ ", n," ------------------------"); tmp=polroots(vp[n]); for (p=1, length(tmp), print(tmp[p])))

------------------------ 1 ------------------------
0.E-38 + 0.E-38*I
1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.E-38*I
2.0000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.E-38*I
3.0000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.E-38*I
4.0000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.E-38*I

------------------------ 2 ------------------------
0.50000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.E-38*I
1.5000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.E-38*I
2.5000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.E-38*I
3.5000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.E-38*I

------------------------ 3 ------------------------
0.66027526411483161194075450403509608522 + 0.E-38*I
1.7500000000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.E-38*I
2.8397247358851683880592454959649039148 + 0.E-38*I

------------------------ 4 ------------------------
0.88762756430420547545067898132352715201 + 0.E-38*I
2.1123724356957945245493210186764728480 + 0.E-38*I

------------------------ 5 ------------------------
1.2500000000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.E-38*I


The text below is between a long comment and a partial answer.
I searched the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences for the coefficients of the "generating" polynomials.
I expect that for the first row (of the matrix $2^n/M_n$) the consecutive coefficients of the polynomial multiplied by $2\cdot n!$ are from the $n+1$th row of the triangle of Stirling numbers of 1st kind. This fits for $n=6$ and for $n=5$ (but the only exception of the term $1600t^2$ which is needed to be $160t^2$ instead. So I guess there is a misprints in you question and suggest to check it. By the way, $105/2$ is the only fractional coefficient of the "generating" polynomials multiplied by $2\cdot n!$ for these $n$ so I suggest to check it too.)
Unfortunately, the above approach failed already for the second row. Luckily, it turned out that for $n=5$ and $n=6$ when for each natural $k\le n-1$ we multiply the coefficient at $t^k$ by $\frac{(-1)^n n!}{2^k}$ then the consecutive coefficients of the polynomial will be from the $n$th row of the triangle of B-analogs of Stirling numbers of first kind.
Unfortunately, the above approach failed for the third row.

Thank you for your remarks; I updated the post with some gp/pari code that finds the generating polynomials and as a matter of fact, there is no misprint for $n=5$. Factorizing the polynomials may help to find a general pattern but it works only for some of them.

Having a look on the roots of these polynomials seems to be of interest as well (see Update 2); this could be an indication that there is likely some relationship/recurrence between these polynomials.
